# ESC < does not work when using ggtags to navigate source files

Tags: key-bindings

I have been using ESC-< or Alt-< to jump to the beginning of the file. After I added ggtags for source navigation, normally it works. But after I press Alt-. to find the declaration/definition of some method/class/variable, 
 pressing ESC-< or Alt-< will instead navigate me back to the previous point from which I pressed Alt-. to navigate to the method or class.

I can still use Alt-g g 1 to go to the beginning of the file. But is there a way to still use ESC-< to go the beginning and assign different binding for ggtags to return to previous position?

Sujan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ggtags [rebinds M-<](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags/blob/master/ggtags.el#L1739) to `#'first-error` in the keymap `ggtags-navigation-map`.

So we can unbind it there:

```
(define-key ggtags-navigation-map (kbd "M-<") nil)
```

And bind something else to it:

```
(define-key ggtags-navigation-map (kbd "C-M-<") #'first-error)
```

Obviously, you can pick another keybinding, as you prefer.

Comment: Thanks...I removed the binding and added a different key.